# David Williams' Exercise 4.5 $\mathbb{P}(\text{limsup}(\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{2\log{n}}})\leq1)=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, martingales, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am attempting Exercise 4.5 from David Williams' ***Probability with Martingales***, which is about **Borel-Cantelli lemma**. The question states the follows.

**If $G$ is a random variable with the normal N(0,1) distribution, then, for $x>0,$ we know that:
$$\mathbb{P}(G>x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_{x}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}\,dy\leq\frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}.$$
Then, let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be a sequence of independent N(0,1) random variables, and define $L:=$limsup$(\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{2\log{n}}}),$  prove that $\mathbb{P}(L\leq1)=1.$**

To approach this question and use Borel-Cantelli lemma, I have made some attempts:

> $$\mathbb{P}(L\leq1)=\mathbb{P}(\text{limsup}(\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{2\log{n}}})\leq1)\stackrel{*}{=}\mathbb{P}(\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{2\log{n}}}\leq1 \text{ eventually})\\
> =\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq\sqrt{2\log{n}} \text{ eventually})=1-\mathbb{P}(X_n>\sqrt{2\log{n}} \text{  infinitly often}).$$
> Then, we can use the information given by the question:
> $$\mathbb{P}(X_n>\sqrt{2\log{n}})\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\log{n}}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\log{n}}=\frac{1}{2n\sqrt{\pi\log{n}}}.$$

But the problem at this step is that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{2n\sqrt{\pi\log{n}}}=\infty,$ and then it seems the Borel-Cantelli lemma can't be applied!

Is there any method to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma to solve this problem? Also, I'm thinking the step of my attempt marked with *:  $\mathbb{P}(\text{limsup}(\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{2\log{n}}})\leq1)\stackrel{*}{=}\mathbb{P}(\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{2\log{n}}}\leq1 \text{ eventually}),$ is it technically correct?

Many thanks in advance for any hints and solutions!

Comment: You have just found that the sum of the probabilities of the events diverges that coupled with the fact that the $X_n$ are independent, gives you the proof (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result).

Comment: @Enrico Yes we found that the sum of the probabilities of the events diverges, but there is a $\leq$ sign in the front, so it seems that this result gives us no information?

Comment: I'd rather try something like $\mathbb P(L \le 1) = \mathbb P( \forall_{m \in \mathbb N_+} L \le 1 + \frac{1}{m})$, hence it is enough to show that $\mathbb P(L \le 1 + \frac{1}{m}) = 1$ for any $m \in \mathbb N_+$. Can you proceed similarly as above? Now the corresponding series should converge

Comment: Premise: I am new to these topics. If the $P(X_n)$ is less than that expression, than $1-P(X_n)$ is greater than something that diverges. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Enrico The standard trick to show that $P(\limsup_{n}Y_n \leq 1) = 1$ is to show that $P(Y_n \leq 1 + \varepsilon \text{ for } n \text{ large }) = 1$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.